# Adding all LDAP-User to jappix friend list

Tags: ldap, xmpp, ejabberd, jappix

we are running jappix with ejabberd als xmpp-server. On ejabberd, there are several ldap hosts configured.

All I want to do is to "prefill" the friend list with all LDAP-Users on all hosts.

At the moment I have to add every user to contact him.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [mod_shared_roster_ldap](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modsharedrosterldap)

Comment: Does anyone have experience adding OpenLDAP-Directory? I could need some hints ...